# Induced Subgraph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G = (V, E)$, be a connected graph with $V$ vertices and $E$ edges. We define $H(x)$ as the number of vertex induced subgraphs with $x$ edges in it.

As per definition, $\sum_{i=0}^{i=m} H(i) = 2^V$. Assume we consider null graph as also one of the induced subgraphs.

For example, let $G(V, E) = \{(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)\}$, where $V = \{1, 2, 3\}$, then $H(0) = 4$, $H(1) = 3$, $H(2) = 0$, $H(3) = 1$.

Also, suppose we write the polynomial $P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{i=m} H(i) * x^i$, then, what can we say about $P(x)$ in terms of $V$ and $E$? This is because it can help us solve the above algorithm efficiently by differentiating the polynomial $E$ times, putting $x = 0$, every time and getting the corresponding coefficient.

Is there an efficient algorithm for the same?

Thanks for your help in advance.

**Update :** Thanks to @Dap, my problem is solved. But I was curious to know if anyone can help with ideas to find $\sum_{i=0}^{i=m} {i}^{k} H(i)$ for fixed $k$ as for variable $k$, the solution will be '#-$P-hard$' as @Dap suggested in one of the comments. For example, what could be possible approaches for say $k = 2, 3, 4$. I found out that for $k = 0$, we have $\sum_{i=0}^{i=m} {i}^{0} H(i) = 2^V$, and for $k = 1$, we have $\sum_{i=0}^{i=m} {i}^{1} H(i) = E * 2^V$.

**Update 2:** The modified problem based on summation $\sum_{i=0}^{i=m} {i}^{k} H(i)$ is also solved now, thanks to @Dap.

Comment: By $G(V,E)=\{(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)\}$ do you mean $V=\{1,2,3\},\ =\{(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)\},\ G=(V,E)?$

Comment: How do you get $\sum_{i=0}^m H(i) = 2^|V|,$ not $2^|V|-1?$ Do you count the "null graph" with no vertices?

Comment: Yes, null graph is also counted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will just discuss the computational problem of computing $P(x)$ from $(V,E)$, with $x$ fixed.

$P(x)$ can be put in the more general context of a "two spin model" partition function,
$$P(x)=\sum_{\sigma:V\to\{0,1\}}\prod_{ij\in E}W_{\sigma(i)\sigma(j)}$$
where
$$W=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&x\end{pmatrix}$$

As well as the case $P(1)=2^V$ you mentioned, there is a polynomial time algorithm to compute $P(-1)$ exactly, and the other cases are NP-hard to compute exactly (in fact "#P-hard"), see [A complexity dichotomy for partition functions with mixed signs](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1932). Note $P(0)$ is the number of independent sets.

For $x>1$ there is an [FPRAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme) to approximate $P(x)$, whereas for $0\leq x<1$ it's NP-hard to approximate. See section 3.3.2 of this survey:  http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2017/6965/
(its Theorem 14 doesn't apply directly to $W$, but if you chase the reference [53] you'll see the NP-hardness is proved even for $\Delta$-regular graphs, and with $\beta=\gamma=\sqrt x$ and $\lambda=\sqrt x^\Delta$ you can show that the partition function comes out the same up to an easily-computed factor.)

Comment: But, one question is although, we can't calculate the coefficients efficiently, is the following problem, where we require to find the value of $\sum_{i=0}^{i=m} i^k H(i)$, for some $k$, also computationally difficult? I was able to come up with formula (using combinatorics) for $k = 0, 1$, but could not proceed further. The formulas were $2^V$ and $E * 2^{V-2}$. Could you please shed some light on it too? Again thanks for help.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I will go through the links you mentioned. Can you mention any link where I can read about difference between "#P-hard" and "NP-hard" as I have never heard about "#P-hard" earlier.

Comment: @joinit: For #P-hardness, I can only suggest [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P) and the description given in Section 2 in that survey article. As for the values $\sum i^k H(i)$, it would be #P-hard to compute exactly if $k$ is given as input, since $P$ can be recovered via linear algebra with a Vandermonde matrix. Maybe it can be computed in polynomial time for each fixed $k$ though.

Comment: thanks for the reply once again. Could you provide hints as to how to approach the problem for fixed $k$, like $k = 2, 3, 4$?

Comment: @joinit: I think this might work: compute $\sum\binom{i}{k}H(i)$ by summing $2^{|V|-|V(F)|}$ over all order $k$ subsets $F\subseteq E$, where $V(F)$ denotes the set of all vertices that the edges in $F$ are incident to. Then it is easy to compute $\sum i^{k'}H(i)$ from the values $\sum\binom{i}{k}H(i)$ with $k\leq k'$.

Comment: Or more directly: $\sum_{w:\{1,\dots,k\}\to E}2^{|V|-|V(\operatorname{im} w)|}$

Comment: thanks once again. The first solution seems quite easy to understand. The idea of formulating the power sum using combinations was quite nice. I am very grateful to you. But I am not able to understand what do you mean in the second solution by $(im w)$? Could you just give an example if possible?

Comment: I meant the image of $w$, so if $w=(ij,ij,ij,jk,jk)$ then $\operatorname{im} w=\{ij,jk\}$ and $V(\operatorname{im} w)=\{i,j,k\}$. Anyway stackexchange is saying these comments are going on too long...